# Auto-click Youtube Embed Videos

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, blogger

I have a webpage on Blogger where I want to embed Youtube videos and play them automatically.

The autoplay function of Youtube either does not work or the views are not recognized.

So I need a script that I can insert in my website which automatically clicks the Youtube videos as soon as the website has loaded and can play.

Comment: In most cases, autoplay gets prevent by the browser these days. Only videos that have no sound, or are muted, are allowed to auto-play - other than that, they would need user interaction to start playing.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use some
Headless Script Browser such as Puppeteer:

> https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer

or PhantomJS:

> https://phantomjs.org/